# Is it possible to tell the version of Retail/OEM/MSDN given a windows 7 iso file?

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible that we can know the version (i.e. OEM, Retail, or MSDN) given a windows 7 ISO file without installation?

Thank you

Comment: Typically you can use the same iso for any key you have.  The only difference is the license itself.

Comment: I've heard that an ISO for OEM will not accept Retail keys, and vice versa. I know that Anytime Upgrade won't let you go from a Retail to MSDN key, but I can't verify this for installations.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have confirmed that Windows 7 Key obtained from MSDN cannot work with ISO from [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on this](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20090725/changes-to-the-windows-7-install-process/)

Even though the install image “install.wim” in Windows 7 still contains four versions, one version is automatically installed determined by a file called “ei.cfg” in the “sources” directory on the install disk.

[How to Select Any Edition or Version (SKU) of Windows 7 to Install From Single Edition DVD Disc Media or ISO](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-select-any-edition-or-version-sku-of-windows-7-to-install-from-single-edition-dvd-disc-media-or-iso/)

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.lunarsoft.net/wiki/Product_IDs is an source to determinate the version. The [Retrieving your product ID or MPC](http://wiki.lunarsoft.net/wiki/Product_IDs#Retrieving_your_product_ID_or_MPC) section tells you how to find the ID on CDs, ISOs or running machines.

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is to find that out is the Channel ID, which is part of the Product ID.

I found this link [Windows 7 Channel ID portion od Product ID](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/18255-Windows-7-Channel-ID-portion-of-Product-ID).  It has a reference to the lunarsoft list mentioned by JohannesM, but mentioned that it contained outdated data.  I'm not sure if this has been updated, as the post is a couple years old.

This link is in reference to Server 2003, but my help you find out more: [How to determine the channel that your copy of Windows Server 2003 was obtained through](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889713)